# Copying hidden files and folders to an external hard disk

Tags: copy-paste, macos

I use an external hard disk as a backup for my programming projects. Now a lot of files in these projects are hidden files. Like .git or .svn etc. I have been able to view the hidden files but I cannot do a copy paste for the hidden files.
Is there something that needs to be activated to allow copying hidden files and folders.

Comment: Can you not copy the enclosing folder, or do you need to cherry-pick the (hidden) files to copy?

Comment: If I copy paste a folder which contains hidden folders, there is a message saying cannot copy this folder because its hidden, I don't remember the exact message but it was something like this.
I had to manually copy the hidden files.